# How to undo class change in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I try to `undo` class change,I suffer some problems.

I could get `clicked` element, but my desired result is to get `class changed` element and `undo` it.

For example in my snippet,I would like to `undo` all the class change at the same time.

In other words, I would like to get`class changed` element `array`.

Are there any method?

Thanks

```js
let clicked=[];

$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(4)').addClass('color');
     let clickedID=$(this).attr('id');
     clicked.push(clickedID);
});
});

$(function() {
  $("#btnCancel").on('click',() => {
    if(clicked.length) {
      let lastClicked = clicked.pop();
      $(`td#${lastClicked}`).removeClass();
    }
  });
  });
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.color {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,60%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td id=1>1</td>
<td id=2>2</td>
<td id=3>3</td>
<td id=4>4</td>
<td id=5>5</td>
<td id=6>6</td>
<td id=7>7</td>
<td id=8>8</td>
<td id=9>9</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button id="btnCancel">undo</button>
```

Comment: `.removeClass('color')`

Comment: It appears your concept is invalid.  `.addClass("colour")` will only add that class if it doesn't already exist.   So even if you used `.removeClass("colour")` (rather than all) it would still remove "all" as there's only 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [`.removeClass([className])`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

**`$('td#${lastClicked}').nextAll(':lt(4)').removeClass('color');` would return the last selected/updated elements.**

```js
let clicked = [];

$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(4)').addClass('color');
    let clickedID = $(this).attr('id');
    clicked.push(clickedID);
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#btnCancel").on('click', () => {
    if (clicked.length) {
      let lastClicked = clicked.pop();
      $(`td#${lastClicked}`).nextAll(':lt(4)').removeClass('color');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color {
  background-color: hsl(60, 100%, 60%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id=1>1</td>
    <td id=2>2</td>
    <td id=3>3</td>
    <td id=4>4</td>
    <td id=5>5</td>
    <td id=6>6</td>
    <td id=7>7</td>
    <td id=8>8</td>
    <td id=9>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="btnCancel">undo</button>
```